# Evisions Argos - Execute a procedure before the report

Tags: oracle, report

We are migrating some reports from Oracle Reports to Evisions Argos. And in Oracle reports, there was a "Before Report" trigger, that would get fired before the actual running of the report query. This allowed us to fill some tables before the query and keep the whole business logic in the report itself. Is it possible to do something like this in Argos? Where could you execute PL/SQL code before running the query for the report? Either at the report or the datablock could work for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a dataset to the report and call the procedure(enclosed with begin/end) there.